# Extending the 'Top' property in Tailwind

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I've tried extending the Tailwind property 'top' with no luck. I'm trying to define a custom variable/height for use as the top property for a sticky element ie `sticky top-controls`:

```
theme: {
   extend: {
     top: {
       controls: 'var(--controls-height)',
     },
   }
 }
```

I'm guessing that the property either cannot be extended, or I'm trying to extend it in the wrong place, however I've not been able to find any reference to doing so in the docs or online. GPT4 suggested adding 'top' in the config file, which didn't sound right to me:

```
  property: {
    top: 'top',
  },
```

GPT3.5 told me that I needed to use the @layer directive, but then went on to simply extend 'top' in the config, like I had already tried.

Would appreciate clarification or a link to which properties can and can't be extended, if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#customizing-your-theme), to add an additional value to `top`, you would extend `spacing`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        controls: 'var(--controls-height)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative top-controls bg-red-500 h-10" style="--controls-height: 20px">
```

Or `inset`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      inset: {
        controls: 'var(--controls-height)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative top-controls bg-red-500 h-10" style="--controls-height: 20px">
```